# Cannot resolve symbol 'baidu', baidumap

Tags: android, baidu

I'm trying to use baidumap in my android app.
Thanks to a chinese friend I succeed to register on the baidu website to be able to access the API.

However trying to import it failed everytime:

```
import com.baidu.mapapi.map.BaiduMap;
```

Sent the error Cannot resolve symbol 'baidu'. I'm unable to import any component related to Baidu. Any ideas?

Comment: Please post your build.gradle file

Comment: Is there some things to add on the gradle file to use baidu ?

Comment: Yes, you will have to add a dependency

Comment: God it was not specified in the doc, I started to find it strange since google maps needed some. I'm gonna look for it. Thanks.